# nested dictionary how to create key and value as nested dictionary value as value .please help me

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
check = {'Test_Category': {0: 'right', 1: 'wrong'}, 'arg1': {0: 'test2', 1: 'test12'},
         'arg2': {0: 'test4', 1: 'test41'}, 'arg3': {0: 'test5', 1: 'test55'},
         'arg4': {0: 'test6', 1: 'test67'}}
```

I want expected result:

```
[{'Test_category': 'right', 'arg1': 'test2', 'arg2': 'test4', 'arg3': 'test5','arg4':'test6'}, 
{'Test_category': 'wrong', 'arg1': 'test12', 'arg2': 'test41', 'arg3': 'test55','arg4':'test67'}]
```

Comment: you didn't even took the time to write your expected result properly.

Comment: anybody having any idea

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, let's try to iterate `check`. We'll take two empty dicts d1 and d2 in which we can add the values. d1 for values of "0"s and d2 for values of "1"s. While iteration, we'll iterate the values which itself is dict and add it accordingly. Your code:

```
check = {'Test_Category': {0: 'right', 1: 'wrong'}, 'arg1': {0: 'test2', 1: 'test12'},
     'arg2': {0: 'test4', 1: 'test41'}, 'arg3': {0: 'test5', 1: 'test55'},
     'arg4': {0: 'test6', 1: 'test67'}}
d1={}
d2={}
for i in check:                #values of check[i] is itself a dict, we need value of 0 key and 1 key of inner dict
    d1[i]=check[i][0]       #values of 0 of inner dict and adding it to d1
for i in check:
    d2[i]=check[i][1]       #values of 1 of inner dict and adding it to d2

l=[d1,d2]         #list of d1 and d2
print(l)        #printing l
```